# Reformat text file in PHP

Tags: php, csv

I have a text file `text.txt` with dates arranged as such.

```
name1
2010-01-02 (i)
2010-05-07 (i)
2010-06-12 (i)
name2
2010-01-02 (i)
2010-05-07 (i)
2010-06-12 (i)
name3
2011-01-05 (i)
2011-05-05 (i)
2011-06-14 (i)
```

I'd like to write the file into 2 columns like:

```
+---------------+-----+
| 2010-01-02 (i)|name1|
| 2010-05-07 (i)|name1|
| 2010-06-12 (i)|name1|  
| 2010-01-02 (i)|name2|
| 2010-05-07 (i)|name2|
| 2010-06-12 (i)|name2|
| 2011-01-05 (i)|name3|
| 2011-05-05 (i)|name3|
| 2011-06-14 (i)|name3|
+---------------+-----+
```

This code is not creating the file as expected.

```
<?php
$path = "text.txt";
$file = file($path);
foreach($file as $value)
{
  $name = "";
  // if ( is found
  if ( strpos($value, "(" ) !== false)
  {
    $date = $value;
    $line = $date . "|" . $name;
    $val = explode("|",$line);
    //write only
    $fp = fopen('data.csv', 'w');
    fputcsv($fp, $val);
    fclose($fp);
  }
  else
  {
    $name = $value;
    //echo $name . "<br />";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Based on your current code, you're only writing out the name ... never.  that `else` is messing you up. I'll write a quick version for you.

Comment: What does the output file look like?

Comment: move `$name = ""` outside `foreach`

Comment: Moving name outside now only gives me the last row of text file. `"2011-06-14 (i)", "name3"`

Comment: `fopen` and `fclose` need to be moved out of the loop also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$path = "text.txt";
$file = file($path);

$fp = fopen('data.csv', 'w+');
$title = array_shift($file);

foreach($file as $value) {
    if (!strpos($value, "(" )){
        $title = $value;
    }
    else {
        $data = array_map('trim', array($value, $title));
        fputcsv($fp , $data, '|');
    }
}
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can try this:

```
<?php
$path = "text.txt";
$file = file($path);
$outputFile = 'data.csv';

$datein = '1998-09-21';
if(preg_match('/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\(i\)$/', $datein)){
    echo 'go';
}else{
    echo 'no go';
}

$fp = fopen($outputFile,'w');

$name = "";
foreach($file as $value)
{


  // match a date-line
  if(preg_match('/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\(i\)$/', $value)) {

     $line = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $value)) . "|" . $name;
     fwrite($fp,$line);
  } else {

      $name = $value;
  }
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Note that I moved the `$name = '';` outside of the loop, and changed it to use regular expressions.  the `trim(preg_replace...` function is there to remove the newline that comes automatically when the line is read and stored into the array.

Comment: All that OP needed is move `name = ""` outside `foreach`. All other stuff simply useless.

Comment: Until someone's name has a parenthesis in it for some reason. Though `preg_match()` *is* more expensive than `strpos()`